# speedup scapy execution - packet sniffing

Tags: sniffing, packet

I'm developing some application that shall monitor some data in real time.
The application shall collect data from the network, parse the relevant packets from my protocol and store it to the database.

When I start the application - everything seems to be OK, but then lags are starting to appear few seconds after that.

Checking my database, it seems that some data is not saved while others does stored (I'm using packet player to inject packets on my PC. Verifying with Wireshark, all the data which has is there ). The data is stored into several tables, and all of the tables have same issue and therefore I'm suspicious on scapy.

Checking the Wireshark statistics, I have about 200 packets per second.

Is there someway to improve the performance of it?

I'm using `sniff(iface="Working", filter = "port 52000", prn=my_parsing_func, store = false)` command

PS - I'm using win 10 OS, python 3.7.4

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. You want to increase the speed of scapy for some reason?

Comment: @Ross Jacobs
Right

Comment: Without additional context, I would say don't use python/scapy. Python is known to be orders of magnitude slower than a compiled language like C. Why not rewrite it in C, C++, or Rust?

Comment: @RossJacobs, I need something flexible that I can rewrite / change without the need of compiling.

Comment: You might be able to get better performance by going with pypy or [another python alternative](https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/). Short of that, change your language. Especially with go, compile times are very fast and so is the speed of the program itself.

Comment: I have a similar question, but I only want to scrape the packet metadata.  There should be a fast & efficient way to do this.